# Adding Cookies for use with Google Chrome Extension Browser Action

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I am trying to create a login system for website. I would like the user to be able to login using the Google Chrome Extension Browser Action and be able to view his private data.

I would like to store a cookie as well as a session for the user to keep him/her logged in while browsing.

```
 chrome.cookies.set({"url": url,"domain": <my-website-domain>, "name": "id", "value": email1, "expirationDate": 100 });
```

The url i am using comes from the chrome.extension.getURL("/") which returns my chrome extension ID.
It does not seem to be working and I cant seem to find my cookie in the resources section of my developer tools window . What could the problem be?